# Distance formula for Longitude and Latitude from two directions

Tags: javascript, gps, distance

For any given latitude and longitude there should exist two distances. Once is clockwise direction and other is anti-clockwise direction. That is how sometimes flights fly too.

Below javascript worked fine in calculating the distance. I'm not sure whether it is clockwise or anti-clockwise. (referring South Down and North up)

What would be the formula to find both directions?

```
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
```

Edit:

I want to calculate clockwise and anti-clockwise path between two points. Practically flights use clockwise and anti-clockwise paths to reach the same point. They don't just use the direct path for commercial and regulatory reasons.

I just want a formula to calculate clockwise and anti-clockwise path to the same point.

Distance wise, the shortest straight path and longest straight path.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the description of the website where you [cut and paste that code](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), you will find that it is the [haversine forumla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and that it provides the shortest distance.

The equation does not give you a simple clockwise or anticlockwise path, it is the most direct 'journey' from point to point.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That would be my primary question. I want to calculate clockwise and anti-clockwise path between two points. Practically flights use clockwise and anti-clockwise paths to reach the same point. They don't just use the direct path for commercial and regulatory reasons.